# Spring (@SpyBean) vs Mockito(@Spy)

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, kotlin, spy

What is the difference between `@SpyBean` from `org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.SpyBean` and `@Spy` from `org.mockito.Spy`?

Using `@SpyBean` instead of `@Spy` makes my [tests](https://github.com/BILLyTheLiTTle/RCCar/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/car/cockpit/dashboard/lights/warning/temperatures/TemperatureCronJobTest.kt) fail.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`@Spy` [doc](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.24.0/org/mockito/Spy.html) says:

> A field annotated with @Spy can be initialized explicitly at
>   declaration point. Alternatively, if you don't provide the instance
>   Mockito will try to find zero argument constructor (even private) and
>   create an instance for you.

`@SpyBean` [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html) says:

> Annotation that can be used to apply Mockito spies to a Spring
>   ApplicationContext.
>
> All beans in the context of the same type will be wrapped with the
>   spy. If no existing bean is defined a new one will be added.

So the main difference is `@SpyBean` is a Spring Boot specific annotation but `@Spy` is part of Mockito itself. `@SpyBean` and `@Spy` basically do the same, but `@SpyBean` can resolve the Spring specific dependencies, e.g. `@Autowired`, `@Spy` can only create object with empty constructor.

Comment: So, `@SpyBean` will load the bean from the instance which already exists in Spring container and `@Spy` will create a totally new object no matter what if already exists in the Spring container or not?

Comment: `@Spy` works as you said, but in case of `@SpyBean` the doc says:
"All beans in the context of the same type will be wrapped with the spy. If no existing bean is defined a new one will be added. "

Answer (score 1):

Something I noticed during testing is that SpyBean can result in certain values being carried over between tests whereas Spy always starts from a clean slate. In my case I had @SpyBean set on a class that initially had autowired components. But after I had refactored the class to remove them I did not change the test classes and I had an unexpected failure.

```
Class1 {
boolean boo;

myMethodA() {
    if (something) {
        boo=true;
    }
}

myMethodB() {
    if (boo) {
      doThis();
    } else { 
      doThat();
    }
  }
}
```

Both Test1 and Test2 used the @SpyBean Class1. Both Test1 and Test2 ran successfully in isolation but when run as a suite Test2 would fail if it ran after Test1.

Test1 set a boolean value in Class1 to true, which was still true when Test2 ran. This caused Test2 to fail as it was expecting the boolean to be false. Changing to
@Spy Class1
resulted in the boolean being reset to false and both tests passing.