# is it the moment to use @SpyBean?

Tags: java, mockito, spy, spybean

i have a bean like this one

```
@Service
public class SpringParent {

    @Resource
    SpringChild sc;

    public String giveChild() {
        return sc.giveChild();
    }

}
```

and a test class like this one..

```
public class InjectMock3 {

    @Spy
    SpringParent sp;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        sp.giveChild();
        verify(sp).giveChild();
    }

}
```

then a message like

```
Cannot invoke "com.coussy.SpringChild.giveChild()" because sc is null
```

So, my question/thinking is :
is it the moment to replace @Spy by @SpyBean
or is there another method ?

Comment: What are you trying to test? `sp.giveChild(); verify(sp).giveChild();` is rather useless – it is obvious that the previous statement has called `giveChild`, why verify the call; don't you trust the compiler and JVM?

Answer (score 0):

Yes

If your bean/component/service etc. is initialized and managed by spring context then you have to use `@SpyBean`

More on this available in `@SpyBean` [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html). Also have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54709589/spring-spybean-vs-mockitospy) which explains differences between `@Spy` and `@SpyBean`

Basically `@Spy` for everything that is not in Spring Context, and `@SpyBean` for everything that managed by Spring Context. This applies for all other counterparts as well for an example `@Mock` vs `@MockBean`